# Editing metadata ALAC files in rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox

I don't seem to be able to edit the metadata of ALAC (apple lossless) files in rhythmbox. Is this even possible or should I use another musicplayer (like Clementine or Banshee, who both can handle the task) to do this (as I'm doing yet)?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify - when you right-click the track and select properties, do you have the fields visible that you can edit?

Comment: Yes, I can see them and they look like I could edit them, but I can't.

Comment: Rhythmbox does not edit the files directly. It only stores any changes in the Rhythmbox music library database itself. You might want to use something like `easytag` instead to edit tags in files.

Comment: Is it possible that Rhythmbox doesn't recognize the tags added with easytag?